# Is there a tag cloud generator for Python code?

Tags: gratis, source-code

I just watched [Kevlin Henney: Seven Ineffective Coding Habits of Many Programmers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZsHMHukIlJY) where he mentions a [SourceCodeCloud](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=sourcecodecloud). This software takes C#, Java, VB.NET projects as input and then, for all related files:

- Remove comments
- Remove strings
- Make everything lowercase

After that, create a tag cloud for it.

Is that possible for Python? Preferable for projects hosted on GitHub as a web service or installable on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Does it  also remove language keywords?